# How do i get space between my input fields in Firefox that appear on Chrome?

Tags: html, css, firefox, input, margin

I want to have three input fields in a larger DIV, so I have

```
    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="searchField" style="width:23%" />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="searchField" style="width:23%">
    <input type="text" name="event" id="event" placeholder="Event" class="searchField" style="width:40%">
```

and I have these styles for the inputs

```
.searchField {
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-align: start;
}
```

However, I notice on Chrome I get space between each input field, which I like, whereas Firefox does not have such space — https://jsfiddle.net/4sjxum1k/12/ .  How can I get space to appear between my inputs in Firefox like Chrome without adversely affecting Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you change `display:text-cell;` to `display:inline-block;`.
So the default word-spacing gets applied to your search fields.

Then you can even change the size of the space by wrapping those fields in a div and styling this div with e.g. `word-spacing:10px;`

Answer (score 0):

I would simply suggest adding break.

```
   <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="searchField" style="width:23%" /><br>
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="searchField" style="width:23%"><br>
<input type="text" name="event" id="event" placeholder="Event" class="searchField" style="width:40%">
```

Comment: Adding break makes everything appear on differnt lines, which I don't want -- https://jsfiddle.net/4sjxum1k/17/ .